# OpenShift 3.11: Edit Prometheus config managed by Operator

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin, prometheus

OpenShift 3.11 has a builtin Prometheus/Alertmanager/Grafana Stack, which is managed by an Operator. The default Prometheus settings are written in a secret called `prometheus-k8s`.

I'd like to know how to edit this configuration without the hassle of exporting it, decoding the base64, encoding it again and re-creating the secret, only in risk that the Operator resets the secret to its default setting.

Is the configuration considered to be editable by Red Hat at all, or should i rather deploy my own Prometheus? Or is there a means to extend this secret with my own configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Resources created by the Cluster Monitoring Operator are entirely managed by the operator. It means that any changes made to them will be overwritten in few minutes when the controller re-syncs. This pattern ensures that the resources are in proper state and that they can automatically be updated without the danger of merge-conflicts.

Also according to this [documentation](https://github.com/openshift/cluster-monitoring-operator):

> The deployed Prometheus Operator is intended to be used only for
>   cluster-level monitoring. As such, the deployed Prometheus instance
>   (prometheus-k8s) is responsible for monitoring and alerting on cluster
>   and OpenShift components; it should not be extended to monitor user
>   applications.

However, if you are interested in using Prometheus for application monitoring you should consider using [OLM](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager) to easily deploy a Prometheus Operator and setup new Prometheus instances for applications monitoring.

Please let me know if that helped.